# JGroups custom logger does not work

Tags: jgroups

I have implemented interfaces (CustomLogFactory, Log) as required in [documentation](http://www.jgroups.org/manual/html/ch02.html#CustomLoggers) but custom logger is not used and no error is displayed when following JVM property is defined

```
-Djgroups.logging.log_factory_class=com.foo.MyCustomLogger
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After little code review I found that exception is not reported by JGroups implementation of `LogFactory` and that `CustomLogFactory` implementation needs to have no-args constructor to be instantiated.

This fact is not mentioned in the documentation as of today and perhaps this post will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Tono,

I changed that code to throw a RuntimeException if the custom log class cannot be found, or the instances cannot be created.
This will be in 3.6.5.